# How to hide "div" from js, which use information from spring?

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, thymeleaf

In my website, on UI I show  information from DB, use "spring". I want to make, if  items quantity equals 0, then I hide this "div". If items quantity more than 0, then I show "div"
In html I recive from spring:

```
<div th:each="viewAvailableWhisky : ${viewAvailableWhisky}">

        <div class="tilt pic" id="ShowHide">
            <a th:href="@{~/buySelectedWhisky(nameBuyWhiskey=${viewAvailableWhisky.id})}" >
                <img  th:attr="src=${viewAvailableWhisky.photo}" id="photoId" width="150" height="250"/>

                <div>
                 <b>   <span th:text="${viewAvailableWhisky.nameWhisky}">Name</span></b>

                </div>
                <div>
                    <b> Quantity: &nbsp; <span  th:text="${viewAvailableWhisky.quantityWhisky}"
                                       >quantityWhisky</span>piece</b>
                    <input type="hidden" id="quantity"  th:value="${viewAvailableWhisky.quantityWhisky}"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <b> $&nbsp; <span  th:text="${viewAvailableWhisky.price}">Price</span></b>
                </div>
            </a>
                      </div>
    </div>
```

I think, it's better to make the with use a JS. But I don't understand how, I try use this code. This code can't catch 
quantity of goods of each item from a DB

```
$(document).ready ( function(){

    var quantityItems = $("#quantity").val();     
    console.log(quantityItems);

    if(quantityItems>0){
        $("#ShowHide").show();
    }
    else {
        $("#ShowHide").hide();
    }
```

});

Comment: `id` can't be duplicated in single document. Here you are creating a HTML in loop; so all will have same id like `ShowHide` and `quantity`. Better to give them only `class` and not `id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The th:if="${condition}" attribute is used to display a section of the view if the condition is met.

```
<span th:if="${student.gender} == 'M'" th:text="Male" />
```

Furthemore, thymeleaf offers option to display certain section if given condition is NOT met using th:unless

```
<span th:unless="${student.gender} == 'M'" th:text="Female" />
```

(For further info see [This tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-in-spring-mvc) or this intro to [Thymeleaf conditionals](http://www.concretepage.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-conditionals-if-unless-and-switch-statements-example))

---

To display certain content only if user has specific role, use spring security's integration with thymeleaf.

```
<div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
  This content is only shown to administrators.
</div>
```

More info about Spring Security integration [here](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springsecurity.html).

Comment: <div class="tilt pic" th:if="${viewAvailableWhisky.quantityWhisky}==0" th:style="display: none"> it's no go

Comment: What do you mean? There should not be display none, it is automatically not displayed based on the fi condition.

Comment: My logic was: if items in DB=0, then "div" must be hiden, else show

Comment: <div class="tilt pic" th:unless="${viewAvailableWhisky.quantityWhisky}==0">

Comment: You were right. How you think, it is posible to do when you have admin rights then you can see all site with items the which equal 0

Comment: You should rather use spring security thymeleaf integration for that. See more here : http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springsecurity.html